# Is there anything wrong in this Generic Interface or Kotlin compiler is not able to infer types?

Tags: kotlin, generics

Assume we have a Adapter interface:

```kotlin
interface EventAdapter<E : Event> {
    val event: E
    // ...
}
```

And a few implementations:

```kotlin
inline class MessageCreateAdapter(override val event: MessageCreateEvent) : EventAdapter<MessageCreateEvent> { /* ... */ }
inline class MessageUpdateAdapter(override val event: MessageUpdateEvent) : EventAdapter<MessageUpdateEvent> { /* ... */ }
// ...
```

And we create an extension to the Event to get respective Adapters:

```kotlin
fun <E : Event> E.toAdapter(): EventAdapter<E>? {
    return when (this) {
        is MessageCreateEvent -> MessageCreateAdapter(this)
        is MessageUpdateEvent -> MessageUpdateAdapter(this)
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Then the compiler complaints that the `MessageCreateAdapter` and `MessageUpdateAdapter` are not `EventAdapter<E>?`. I cannot figure out what's the problem, or the case where this does not hold.

[image]
<sub>Attached a minimal compilation error message</sub>

Comment: Does it work when the classes aren't inline?

Comment: @mowwwalker nope: https://pl.kotl.in/liYup6nmX

Comment: I was wrong, the problem is that the compiler cannot check at compile time that `EventAdapter<E>?` is the parent type of `MessageCreateAdapter` or `MessageUpdateAdapter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler infers type of that `when` expressinon as a most specific supertype of `MessageCreateAdapter` and `MessageUpdateAdapter` (+ nullable), which is `EventAdapter<out Event>?`. The problem is that compiler is not trying to proof that evaluation of this expression is dependent of `E`, so that resulting type could be not just most specific supertype of all `when` branches, but emphasized via `E`, so you need to help him and do some manual casting:

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <E : Event> E.toAdapter() : EventAdapter<E>? {
    return when(this) {
        is MessageCreateEvent -> MessageCreateAdapter(this) as EventAdapter<E>
        is MessageUpdateEvent -> MessageUpdateAdapter(this) as EventAdapter<E>
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a case where this doesn't hold: when `is MessageCreateEvent` (for example) matches, it doesn't mean that `E` is `MessageCreateEvent`; it could be e.g. just `Event`. In that case you are required to return an `EventAdapter<Event>`. But you return a `MessageCreateAdapter` which extends `EventAdapter<MessageCreateAdapter>`, not `EventAdapter<Event>`.

If you used `interface EventAdapter<out E : Event>`, I think it could theoretically work, but still won't for the reason given in Михаил Нафталь's answer.

Comment: Yeah, completely forgot about the explicit generic passing .

Comment: No need for explicit passing, just call it on a `val e: Event` :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov can you clarify that? If `is MessageCreateEvent` matches, in what case would `E` not be `MessageCreateEvent`? You say it could just be `Event`, but if that's the case, how would it have matched `MessageCreateEvent`?

Comment: @mowwwalker if I am correct generics only exist at compile time, atleast non-reified ones. So if I store an event like `val ev: Event = MessageCreateEvent(...)` and call `ev.toAdapter()` then E is basically assumed to be passed as `Event` rather than `MessageCreateEvent` since we are not dealing with generics at runtime. :)

Comment: Well, this would work the same in a language with non-erased generics as well (e.g. C#). It's just that if `E` is `Event`, `this` can be any value of type `Event`, including a `MessageCreateEvent`.